# Discord.js - Problem with promises being "overwritten"?

Tags: javascript, request, discord, discord.js, request-promise

Alright, so I'm practically finished with this Discord Bot that I have been building in JS. 
I'm having a problem with new promises being resolved before old ones have completed, resulting in incorrect information being sent to the wrong server.

My "!armory" command for instance-
What this does is:
(requires an item argument from user- accepted args: xanax, morphine, blood bag, refill)
Make a request-promise.post -> if request successful -> send "loading..." message -> then make a separate request.post -> on success edit "loading..." message with results from users args.

The HTTP being requested contains a list of users from my Torn.com faction, and the items they have used from our faction armory.
So the message that is sent in the edit, contains all users and how many of the items given in the argument that they've used.

The problem I am having, is when someone does the command twice, whether in the same server or not; the results from the last command use is given to everyone.

Example: User in server one uses the command to get xanax usage like so "!armory xanax"...
While promise is still being resolved, User in server 2 uses the command to get morphine usage like so "!armory morphine"...

Once the 2nd promise has resolved, the morphine results from the command used in server 2 are sent to both servers in the edit message.

I expect each server to get their respective results.

**EDIT to add code**

````
let configJson = fs.readFileSync(`./config.json`);
let configObj = JSON.parse(configJson);
const server_api_get = 'https://torn.market:8443/getarmoury';
const server_api_update = 'https://torn.market:8443/updatearmoury';

updateData = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: server_api_update,
    form: {
        API_KEY: configObj.guilds[message.guild.id].key,
        end_date: endDate, // - End Date Dropdown on Faction page(Date furthest from today)
        start_date: startDate, // - Start Date Dropdown on Faction page(Date closest to today)
    },
};
//
getData = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: server_api_get,
    form: {
        API_KEY: configObj.guilds[message.guild.id].key,
        end_date: endDate, // - End Date Dropdown on Faction page(Date furthest from today)
        start_date: startDate, // - Start Date Dropdown on Faction page(Date closest to today)
    },
};

//
rp(updateData)
    .then(function (body) {
        // POST succeeded...
        updateJson = JSON.parse(body)
        console.log(body);
        if (updateJson.message === "Update Successful") {
            let responseTitle = '';
            console.log(` - New request -\nDate/Time: ${Date()}\n` + updateJson.message)
            embed.setColor('BLUE')
                .setTitle('`Loading Faction Armory use for ' + type + '......`')
            message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {
                rp(getData)
                    .then(function (body) {
                        responseMsg = '';
                        embed.setColor(`GREEN`)
                            .setTitle(responseTitle)
                            .setDescription("```coffeescript\n" + responseMsg + "\n```")
                        msg.edit(embed)
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        // POST failed...
                        errJSON = JSON.stringify(err)
                        errObj = JSON.parse(errJSON)
                        console.log(`${errObj.name}\n${errObj.message}`);
                    });
            })
        } else {
            console.log(`Code: ${updateJson.error}\nError: ${updateJson.message}\nWrong API_KEY or no Faction API Access.`);
        }
    })
````

Comment: Sounds like you are storing the result of the promise in a global variable then somehow poll for the promise completion. You should not do that. Instead you should handle the response directly in the promise's `then()` callback

Comment: You forgot to add code to your question. Without it we cannot know what you did (wrong).

Comment: @trincot - I thought the code might be too long. And it's difficult for people to replicate due to needing an API key for the requests. Perhaps I should link a pastebin?

Comment: we don't need *all* your code, if you can insert the general structure of it, including how your promises are called and resolved, this should be a goot starting point to figure out what should be modified.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex).

Comment: @trincot I've added the main part of my code

Answer (score 0):

Ugh I'm an idiot...

I just needed to define a blank 'type' variable the same way I did responseTitle and responseMsg....

```
let type = '';
```

'type' is made from args given by command user like so:

```
let responseTitle = '';

    if (newArgs.includes("xa")) {
        type = "Xanax";
        responseTitle = "Xanax used from Armory\n__*" + endDate + "*__ to __*" + startDate + "*__\n"
    } else if (newArgs.includes("morph")) {
        type = "Morphine";
        responseTitle = "Morphine used from Armory\n__*" + endDate + "*__ to __*" + startDate + "*__\n"
    } else if (newArgs.includes("bb") || newArgs.includes("blood bag") || newArgs.includes("blood") || newArgs.includes("bag")) {
        type = "BloodBag";
        responseTitle = "Blood Bags used from Armory\n__*" + endDate + "*__ to __*" + startDate + "*__\n"
    } else if (newArgs.includes("re")) {
        type = "Refill";
        responseTitle = "Blood Bags refilled from Armory\n__*" + endDate + "*__ to __*" + startDate + "*__\n"
    } else if (newArgs.includes("sf")) {
        type = "SFAK";
        responseTitle = "Small First Aid Kits used from Armory\n__*" + endDate + "*__ to __*" + startDate + "*__\n"
    } else if (newArgs == "fak") {
        type = "FAK";
        responseTitle = "First Aid Kits used from Armory\n__*" + endDate + "*__ to __*" + startDate + "*__\n"
    }
```